# whats the parameters indicate in the method public void onScroll (AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)'

Tags: android

actually i need to use onscrolllistener in my app but i could not understand whats does the parameters indicate  in the method public void onScroll (AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount),please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#onScroll%28android.widget.AbsListView,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), you can easily know all these parameter.

Even though here i explain in my language.

```
view : View for which we implemented this listener

firstVisibleItem : Index of very first visible row/cell at a time

visibleItemCount : Total number of visible rows/cells

totalItemCount : Total number of items in the list adapter
```